# I need a html5 input box type time, that works in all browsers?

Tags: html, typescript, angular

**Does anyone know how to create an html input box that formats time?**

I have an input box and I tried giving it the type time instead of text and it doesnt work across all browsers.

I'm using angular2 with typescript and html5

I need to make sure the user types into the time input box in the correct format.

I cant seem to get any jquery solutions working for this either.

Does anyone have any good demos I can copy?

**This is my current code:**

```
 <input class="form-control col-xs-6" class="timepicker" id="JobStartTime" type="time" placeholder="Start time" [(ngModel)]="jobStartTime" />
```

This only works in chrome.

I need this to work in all browsers

Comment: I think you could do a regex-pattern

Comment: Google : input type date

Comment: doesnt work across all browsers that

Comment: use a Date Pipe: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/DatePipe-class.html

Comment: I dont need a filter. I need a input box that formats to time

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" value="2015-08-09">
```

You may try like this.

Comment: Yup. it works for Chrome, Firefox and latest version of IE

Comment: do you know one for time? that works across all browsers?

Comment: OK great. Mark this as correct answer and vote up (If its really helpful)

Comment: For example the date answer above and time types wont work in firefox. only chrome.